# Thread-Safe Pandas variables

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, multiprocessing

I realize that using the multiprocessing module would be better in this situation, but I'm working on a server where it takes several days to add modules (I'm not the administrator), and I would prefer to get this working sooner than later.

I have code that is not thread safe, and if possible I'm trying to figure out how to make it thread safe. (Code below)  My locally designed modules work when I am not using threading.

```
import sys, threading
from school.school_func import run_school_report
from class.class_func import run_class_report
from common.getdata import get_data         #locally designed module
import pandas as pd

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, task, year, month, c1, c2, data):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.task = task
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.class1= c1
        self.class2= c2
        self.data = data
    def run(self):
        if self.task == "school_report":
            run_school_report(self.year, self.month, self.class1, self.class2, self.data)
            print("\nSchool report finished! \n")
        else:
            run_class_report(self.year, self.month, self.class1, self.class2)
            print("\nClass reports finished!\n")

#main script
YEAR = 2017
MONTH = 3
C1, C2, DATA = get_data('mysql', reload=False, blacklist=True)
t1 = myThread("school_report", YEAR, MONTH, C1, C2, DATA)
t2 = myThread("class_reports", YEAR, MONTH, C1, C2, DATA)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
print("NOTICE:\nAll tasks successfully completed!\n\n")
```

The variables C1, C2, DATA, and the class variables assigned their values are `pandas.DataFrame` objects.

My questions are this:

1) Is it possible to make this code thread safe?

2) Should I bite the bullet and use multiprocessing?

Comment: `multiprocessing` is a core python module, if you have `threading` you also have `multiprocessing` unless you're running some special build of python where some core modules have specifically been dropped?

Comment: huh, I'm fairly new to python, obviously, but it appears that you are correct.  Maybe I was misspelling it.  How embarrassing.

Comment: no worries, I'll add the comment as an answer so you can accept it and the question gets closed off as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing` is a core python module, if you have `threading` you also have `multiprocessing` unless you're running some special build of python where some core modules have specifically been dropped?